# Test the log in functionality of a web page with incorrect credentials

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ecmascript-6

I'm new to playwright, so I'm unsure if this is the correct or best way to go about testing. I basically want multiple tests on the same webpage. I've been able to successfully accomplish this using test.beforeAll:

```
test.describe("sign in with an invalid email/password combination", () => {
  let page;
  test.beforeAll(async ({ browser }) => {
    const context = await browser.newContext();
    page = await context.newPage();
    await page.goto("https://www.example.com");
    await page.getByRole('link', { name: 'Sign In' }).click();

    const username = "user@gmail.com";
    const password = "verysecure";
    const userField = page.getByLabel("Email or phone number");
    const passwordField = page.getByLabel("Password");

    await userField.fill(username);
    await passwordField.fill(password);
    await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Sign in' }).click();
  });

  test("one", async () => {
    await expect(page).toHaveTitle("Title");
  });
  test("two", async () => {
    await expect(page.locator('[data-uia="text"]')).toHaveText(
      "Incorrect password. Please try again or you can reset your password."
    );
  })
})
```

Reading through the [docs](https://playwright.dev/docs/next/auth#reuse-signed-in-state) it states:

> Redoing login for every test can slow down test execution. To mitigate that, reuse existing authentication state instead.

And I found this [stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68699387/can-you-run-multiple-tests-in-one-browser-context-playwright-javascript) on how to share the same page across multiple tests. My confusion is whether or not my code is opening new pages and attempting to sign in for each test. Also, if I should be using storageState, or if beforeEach is appropriate in this situation? I only plan on testing pieces of the webpage, not actually ever logging in.

Comment: No, what you see is not the actual URL, I just used that for this post. Thanks, I've updated the title, I hope it's more appropriate.

Comment: The IANA-designated domains for examples have `example` in the name - e.g. `example.net`, `example.org`, `example.com`.  You should be using one of those, or passing the URL as a parameter.

Comment: I further edited the title so that it describes the _purpose_ of the code rather than how it's implemented, per [site goals](/questions/how-to-ask).  Please check that I haven't misrepresented your code, and correct it if I have.

Comment: Not sure what to even change the title to anymore, but I am not testing all functionality or logging in.

Comment: If you're not sure what it does, it's not ready for review. Please take a look at the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To figure out whether your code is being run twice, you should be able to put a `console.log` in and see what's going on.

Because of the complexity of the setup (that you are seeing), in-browser tests require a different approach than unit tests. Whereas in unit tests you want to isolate logic, in these tests you will likely go through a whole flow for a user, and include multiple assertions throughout.

I have read the advice about using existing authentication state that you are quoting, and it seems like you're asking the right question. You *can* create a global setup (which I have done), and run your tests in sequence. I tend to *not* do this, though, as it couples the tests together, and if something goes wrong in one test, it can affect another. For me, a very important principal in test maintenance is **test isolation**. If the tests are linked like that, I ask, why not make just one longer test? It will be clearer to future readers what is happening.

So I tend to write longer tests that are isolated from each other. Playwright will nicely parallelize these and save time. I would recommend avoiding the advice you are quoting until speed is a real issue for your test suite. This happens periodically with a large, slow test suite, at which point sharing auth may (or may not) be the right choice.

Thanks for sharing! I'm not sure why the downvotes are there.

Comment: I'll try logging to find out more. Thanks for the advice! You've given me much to look into.